# No activity on clicking button after deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, webforms

I have a webform that had been working fine since months. All of a sudden it has stopped functioning. No post back events are being fired. I check console of browser and couldn't find anything that could have caused the problem. There have been no changes on the server. Entire application is working fine except for one particular webform. Surprising thing is that the same published code is working on local machine,even server, but when i check the client browsers after publishing it on server.. I get the same issue. I checked the "Timeline" tab in chrome browser on click submit button.. there is absolutely no activity. Has anyone faced any such issue before?

**UPDATE:**

I am not sure what code to post here because there is nothing that looks suspicious. I am posting just a small fragment of the code :

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (rbltype.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Type field is mandatory.');", true);
                return;
            }
            if (((DataTable)ViewState["GridTable"]).Rows.Count < 1)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Minimum one row is mandatory');", true);
                return;
            }

            Insert("save");

        }
```

**ASPX:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ModuleMain.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="EmployeeGoalSetting.aspx.cs"  Inherits="UNO.EmployeeGoalSetting" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">


        window.onload = function () {
            var strCook = document.cookie;
            if (strCook.indexOf("!~") != 0) {
                var intS = strCook.indexOf("!~");
                var intE = strCook.indexOf("~!");
                var strPos = strCook.substring(intS + 2, intE);
                document.getElementById("grdWithScroll").scrollTop = strPos;
            }
        }
        function SetDivPosition() {
            var intY = document.getElementById("grdWithScroll").scrollTop;
            document.cookie = "yPos=!~" + intY + "~!";
        }



    </script>

// lots of code 

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" 
                    Text="Save And Submit" />
```

Comment: How about adding some paragraphs and example code to your one-large-block of text?

Comment: Could be the result of a variety of things. Are you sure nothing has changed on the server? Are you in complete control of the server or is it a third party host that may have updated something on their end that broke your application?

Comment: @UweKeim I would but I am not sure what part of the code should I post? It's pretty big form with lots of code. And no buttons or linkbuttons are working right now. I dont think the problem is with code because same code has been working for months.

Comment: @JayGould I am not 100% sure that nothing has changed on the server. It is managed by my company but a different team and I have checked with them. They claim that there has been no change. 
If there had been any change on the server the published code should not work on server right?

Comment: @Arbaaz at this point, anything anyone tells you without seeing code before and after the break is a guessing game. The first (and only) thing that jumps to mind is that something changed backend on the server overnight and that's made your form break. Can you post the code that isn't working in an `update` in your main post please?

Comment: @JayGould I am really not sure what code to post. The code is huge. But nothing looks suspicious. I have updated my code.

Comment: @JayGould it feels like something is blocking postback requests from this webform all of a sudden. When I click on the submit button the loading semi circle at the top keeps rotating in chrome but nothing happens. AT ALL. No errors, no activity in network tab. It's like browser is blocking it without displaying any messages.

Comment: @Arbaaz have you tested it in multiple browsers?

Comment: @JayGould yes, chrome and mozilla

Comment: @Arbaaz it may be a firewall issue then. Are you able to test it on a different network, or host a copy of your webform elsewhere (off your current server) for testing?

Comment: Do you get any error in the debugging console of the browser? A javascript error could break the postback.

Comment: @JayGould It's working everywhere , I have not test on another server yet. I will update as soon as I do.

Comment: @AndreiRînea there are two or three javascript errors but i dont think that is the reason since they have always been there.  For eg: there is a 404 status for webticker.js but this webticker is not even used anywhere on the webform, may be masterpage.

Comment: Try something else then: right click on the button, select 'Inspect element' (or how it's called in your browser's inspection tool) and go along the javascript's path. Put a breakpoint in the javascript function and click the button for real. See how the execution path goes.

Comment: @JayGould I hosted it on a different server and it was working fine. I have narrowed down the location of problem. The issue seems to occur when deployed on that particular server and that too when webform is accessed from within the organization (other webforms are working fine both from within and outside the organization). The same webform is working fine on the same server when accessed from outside. (i checked from my home).

Comment: @Arbaaz strange, but at least it's progress. Have you spoken to a sysadmin regarding it?

Comment: @JayGould Yes I have, they are looking into it. I have  never faced any such issue before.